# Cannot access anything in C drive in Windows 8.1

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, windows-explorer

My colleague seemed to have accidentally tampered with some security options in `C:` drive and now seemed to have locked herself out of any direct access to the C drive.

The following is the dialog content displayed:

> This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.

But the user *is* the administrator (well technically).

After I searched for this problem in the Internet, all I could find is about issues related to program installation problems like Chrome. However, Chrome was successfully installed and working in the system as long before this happened.

This is what happened prior to this problem:

Right Click on C: `->` Properties `->` Security tab `->` Advanced button

In the Advanced Security Settings for Local Disk (C:), clicked on 'Change'. In the text box, she typed her username *X*.

After noticing this problem, she typed the name back to the default *TrustedInstaller* in an attempt to reverse what happened. Alas, the problem still persisted.

A matter to note is that the **command prompt is working fine in `C:`, but nothing in `C:` can be accessed from the Explorer**. This includes all User folder such as Documents, Downloads, etc. as well as the drive itself.

What could be the solution for this problem?

Comment: Try giving Full Control to your user and check once.

Comment: @vembutech: Yep, we tried that, but still no change.